# How to get My Google Blogger's Post Lists using flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-blogger-api

I'm searched for getting google blog post list with flutter on google. But no more example with flutter. Is that possible? How can I do that? Thank You

Comment: which "google blog"?

Comment: Thank you Sir. I would like to get lists of my google blogger posts with flutter

Comment: I think Google blogs have a rss link. RSS is a xml. You can work on this

Comment: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/getting_started